# Alternative To Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-api, google-places-api, geo

The project I am working on uses google places autocomplete to help users to input POIs and addresses. This works ok but we want to filter the autocomplete results by particular areas which we define in polygons.

As google does not send the latitude and longitude in the response it is not possible to use their api. Of course we could send a second request to retrieve this data but it doesn't seem like a good solution both performance and data usage wise.

I have looked into the foursquare search api. This works ok but the support for addresses is poor, the api is mostly based on POIs.

Are there any alternatives to google places that return both addresses and POIs?

Comment: You may wanna take a look on Open Street Maps.

Comment: @bribeiro yeah I am doing that with mapquest but I still can't find a nice solution

Answer (score 5):

1) TomTom
2) Mapbox
3) HERE
4) MapFit
5) Leaflet
6) OpenLayers
7) LocationIQ
8) AND
9) Sygic Maps
10) Jawgmaps

Comment: do you know how to achive autocompete in leaflet ?

Answer (score 4):

Looking around into options myself at the moment. You might want to give [Pelias](https://github.com/pelias/pelias/) a go. Main reason I'm looking away from Google Places is due to the licensing restrictions.

Comment: it's 2018 and Mapzen Shutdown :(

Comment: @msm2020, Mapzen has shut down but [Pelias](http://github.com/pelias/pelias/) is going strong. The project has continued to improve with several companies small and large, and several individuals, contributing to the code base. There are options for hosted Pelias, support, and custom development.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated my answer so it links to the github repo

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried TomTom Search API?

[Geometry search endpoint](https://developer.tomtom.com/search-api/search-api-documentation-search/geometry-search) allows you to do a search within defined polygon.